# Can Javascript get a selection from outside the browser?

Tags: javascript, selection

How can a Javascript script running within a browser obtain a window system selection from a region outside the browser? For example, in scan mode, StarDict, a Java program not running in a browser, responds to a selection event in, say, an xterm or pdf viewer, by looking up the selected text. How can a Javascript program running in a browser respond similarly? As far as I can tell, everything having to do with selection in Javascript is with respect to the DOM and therefore internal to the browser.

Comment: If you could listen in to something on the user's machine, that would be a huge security risk, so there shouldn't be any way to do that.  The only way would be if the user's computer was operating some kind of service that would reply to let's say a query to http://127.0.0.1:8080/get-data ... if the app can listen on a port and respond to such a request, then you could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

The slightly longer answer is you could write a browser extension that interacts with the system outside the sandbox and use that to communicate with your page. But you then have the trouble of getting your users to install your extension and convince them that is isn't a huge security risk.

Comment: That is as I feared. Thanks.